# why index value is not changed after drag and drop in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

this is my html

```
 <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="name in names"><div ng-click="indexfind($index)">{{name.myname}}</div></li>
 </ul>
```

this is my controller

```
  $scope.names=[{"myname":"john"},{"myname":"britto"},{"myname":"franklin"}];
  $scope.indexfind=function(index)
  {
   alert(index);
  }
```

here three li tag will be created and then i did drag and drop for this li tags but drag and drop index value have not changed automatically in the $scope.names array .so i have used splice method to remove and add value while sortable start and stop event.so i did like this

```
 var dragdrop=angular.element('#sortable'); 
 dragdrop.sortable({

        start: function(event, ui) {

          from=$(ui.item).index();


              $scope.names.splice(from, 1);

        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {

         var to=$(ui.item).index();
          $scope.names.splice(to, 0,obj);


        },
 });
```

now $scope.names array index coming properly while doing sortable but when i click on div after sotrable it is showing index value wrongly ..that means it is showing previous index value it is not showing new index value (after sortable index value).
what mistake i did ? how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using jQuery draggable?

Comment: i am using jquery ui sortable....

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because Angular is "not aware" of the changes that are happening when you sort the data, try to manually fire a digest cycle after the sort is done.

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Add the line above to the stop function:

```
 var dragdrop=angular.element('#sortable'); 
 dragdrop.sortable({

    start: function(event, ui) {

      from=$(ui.item).index();


          $scope.names.splice(from, 1);

    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {

      var to=$(ui.item).index();
      $scope.names.splice(to, 0,obj);

      $scope.$apply();  
    },
 });
```

Comment: puff.. in that case I'd recommend you to set a fiddle to make it easier for us to help you